# How do you extract text and styling from a Static GIF?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, adobe-fireworks

I have a static non-animated GIF image, is there anyway to extract a line of text and/or its font formatting information from it? I've tried opening it in GIMP, but the whole image appears to be only a single layer.

Comment: Can you post a link to the image?

Comment: @BenHawker I cannot, it is confidential. It is a header for a desktop application, and also can be used for the website, similar to this one I found online: [link](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/inverted_tabs/header.gif)  Are there anyway to split the layers in GIFs, like how Fireworks can split different PNG levels?

Comment: As far as I know Fireworks can only edit layers on [Fireworks PNGs](https://www.adobe.com/support/fireworks/export/fw_export_vs_sav/fw_export_vs_sav02.html). Once a PNG is flattened it can't "peel it apart". Same goes for GIFs.

Comment: If your goal is to extract the text portion of a larger image then select the text portion..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few techniques I know of for extracting this information from an image.

## [What the Font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

What the font allows you to upload an image of your text and it tries to match the characters to a font. I recommend cropping your image down to just the text before uploading for best results.

## [Project Naptha](https://projectnaptha.com/)

Project Naptha is a Chrome extension which OCR's images and allows you to copy the text. This will get you the text content (more or less) but not the formatting or styling.

## Illustrator / Photoshop

Once you've used What the Font (which may give you more than one option) you can try the retyping the text in Illustrator or Photoshop. I often line up the new text over with 50% opacity so I can figure out the weight, kerning, baseline and leading. In Illustrator this is all done using the *Character* panel (*Windows > Type > Character*).

### Example

I did this recently with the Logo for the National Center for Biomedical Ontology. Here's the original logo (I only had a JPEG).

[image: Original Logo]

I didn't know what font it was so I cropped it down to just the big letters for What the Font.

[image: Cropped Logo]

Then I uploaded it to What the Font, it got all of the letter except for the "I"'s, which I fixed.

[image: What the Font Analysis]

What the Font said it was *Arial Narrow* so I started trying to fit that to the logo.

[image: Fitting in Progress]

I had to tweak the kerning for a few letter to get them lined up. In the it's never going to be exactly the same placement as the original but it's pretty close.

[image: Final Text Fit]